# How to remove an appimage's user mofied settings after or before deleting the appimage file?

Tags: linux, appimage

I launched an **appimage** using **appimagelauncher**. Then, I modified some settings of that app.

I know that **appimages** are not installed, so *it can't be uninstalled*. So, I deleted the **appimage** file.

But, when I downlaoded the **appimage** again, I observed that the user's previously modified settings were still there.

Now, how can I completely remove those user modified settings and launch that software as if it were newly installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppImage format doesn't define an explicit place where the applications configuration should be installed. Which means that the application can write such file wherever they please (as a regular installed application does).

Applications usually write their configurations to "$HOME/.config", you can look there for a file or folder with the application name. You can also ask the application author or check the documentation.